# Сделать подсчет уникальных записей если есть except

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Здравствуйте нужно сделать подсчет уникальных индексов при том что есть except.
Вот как выглядит сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно просто вывести цифру 4 (кол-во строк на данной картинке).
Вот мой код:

```
select distinct customer_id as kol_left_this_company
from sales_order
where order_date<'31.12.1990' 
except
select distinct customer_id as kol_left_this_company
from sales_order
where order_date>'31.12.1990'
```

Comment: Заверни свой код в `WITH` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) а из него уже делай `SELECT` `COUNT`. И туда бы я вынес `distinct`.

Comment: Второй вариант `SELECT` from `SELECT`. можно подсмотреть, например, тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961349/using-select-result-in-another-select/15961540

Comment: `select count(*) from ( ... ) as foo`, вместо троеточия твой sql